# Azure tables access rules

Tags: sql, azure, xamarin, mobile-application

Sorry for may be simple question. I not experienced with server-based apps developing.
I study Azure recently and create simple mobile application that connect to azure database. Its make some trivial operations on tables like add items and make SQL select queries. Now I want add authorisation to app and restrict some operations with tables in db based on it. What is best way to do it? I think it's a good idea to write backend on azure server with authorisation-based rules but I don't find out about it from Azure documentation. For example what I want to achieve:

1. Not authorisation mobile app user restricted to make any modifying operations and can select only predefined columns.
2. Authorisation user can make add/update operations on some tables based on user info(uid/login etc...).

If I create database rules on frontend(mobile app) side its not difficult to write another app that have possibility to make anything with database in bypass of my app. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> If I create database rules on frontend(mobile app) side its not difficult to write another app that have possibility to make anything with database in bypass of my app. Isn't it?

This is very true; security shouldn't be (just) in the frontend. Make sure your backend is set up in such a way it checks the access rules each time someone tries to do something in the backend.

Now, as far as your question goes: please implement an API that connects to your database. With each and every client directly connecting to your database, you will lose all control. If you implement an API in front, you can do stuff like caching and asynchronous processing if you need to.

When implementing the API, you can have the GET methods be unsecured, while POST, PUT and DELETE use a (for instance) JWT token retrieved from Azure Active Directory. [This repo](https://github.com/rickvdbosch/SAFwAD) and the presentation it links to might give you some reference.